Bootstrap 5 Image and text on it
I have Bootstrap 5 website template and I need to add text with white background on the center image.
And in this case, I see a white color instead image but I want to white rectangle with a title and text in the center of the image


.our-company-title {
  line-height: 31px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.our-company-text {
  color: #787878;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.contact-image-box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 p-0 position-relative">
      <div class="position-relative">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100 object-fit-cover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="">

        <div class="contact-image-box">
          <h3 class="our-company-title">Title</h3>
          <p class="our-company-text">Company text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-md-center">
      content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Also I tried this, but title and text align left but not center:
.contact-image-box {
    max-width: 400px;
}


Be aware that Bootstrap offers classes for much of your custom CSS properties, such as position, flex, heading styles, and color. You should avoid duplicating effort by getting to know the library better.

You want to add the background-color to the h3 and p like this:


.our-company-title{
    line-height: 31px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.our-company-text{
    color: #787878;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.contact-image-box {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    /* background-color:#fff; */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 p-0 position-relative">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100 object-fit-cover" loading="lazy" src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1700268374954-f06052915608" alt="">
                <div class="contact-image-box">
                    <h3 class="our-company-title">Title</h3>
                    <p class="our-company-text">Company text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-md-center">
        content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




my suggestion is to use inner div inside that contact-image-box. this div should contain that text and stuff, .contact-image-box div on the other hand, should be a container. give those flexbox properties to that container div, then add that white background color to the inner div.
it should be something like this:


.contact-image-box { 
  inset: 0; // this is equivalent to the top, bottom, left and right set to 0
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
        
   & > div {
     background-color: white;
   }

}



